# Using jq to add/prepend an element to the top of an array

Tags: arrays, jq, prepend

I have the following json file (example.json):

```
{
  "examples": [
    {
      "example": "2"
    },
    {
      "example": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to use jq to add a new element to the top of this array (rather than the bottom). All the solutions I've come up with simply add it to the bottom (code I'm using below):

```
jq '.examples +=
[{"example": "1",
}]' example.json
```

The desired output (in case it's not immediately obvious) would be:

```
{
  "examples": [
    {
      "example": "1"
    },
    {
      "example": "2"
    },
    {
      "example": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can concatenate arrays with `+` so you can add your new object inside an array and concat the rest:

```
.examples |= [{example: "1"}] + .
```

https://jqplay.org/s/XIsoZ4GvOa